# How to update the local storage value?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I already searched lots of stuffs but none of them helped me. What I want to achieve is whenever I set an Item to my localstorage, I can also update that specific Item. Now, how to change/update the value of local storage? Im trying but It doesn't work.

NOTE: Im building an ionic app.

Here's my code:

```
.factory('Auth', [function () {

  if(window.localStorage['session']){
  var _user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['session']);
  }

  var setUser = function(session){
  _user = session;
  window.localStorage['session'] = JSON.stringify(_user);
 }


return {

  setUser: setUser,
  isLoggedIn: function(){
    return _user ? true : false;
  },
  getUser: function(){
    return _user;
  },
  logout: function(){
    window.localStorage.removeItem("session");
    window.localStorage.removeItem("list_dependents");
    _user = null;
    }
} 


}])
```

**app.js**

```
Auth.setUser({
  name: 'Kean',
  sex: 'Male'
});

alert(Auth.getUser(0).name);
// works fine.

//But when I update the name like this:
Auth.setUser(0).name = "Allen";

// It does not work.
```

Am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Look at the difference in setUser and getUser in your return statement. Calling setUser() does nothing.

Comment: Shouldn't you update the name calling `Auth.getUser(0).name = ...` instead of `Auth.setUser(...`?

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: it doesn't make sense to pass `0` to `setUser()`.  As written, you are saying "pass the function a `0`", then in the function, you are saying, "`set `_user to what was passsed in (`0`)", then "stringify `_user`" (whose value is `0`).  On top of that, `setUser` doesn't return anything, so `setUser(0).name` won't work anyway.

Comment: Please give me a code that updates data

Comment: based on the last comment, this question is immediately getting a downvote from me.  It's clear you don't really understand how this code works; someone "giving you a code" won't help you to understand what is going on, or how to fix this kind of thing in the future, much less help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem! Thanks for the replies:

I just added this line inside `return`

```
 updateUser: function(updatedUser){
    var the_user = this.getUser();
    for(var attr in the_user){
      if(updatedUser[attr]&& updatedUser[attr] !== the_user[attr]){
        the_user[attr] = updatedUser[attr];
      }
    }
    this.setUser(the_user);
  }
```

And when I update specific data

```
Auth.updateUser({name: "A new Name"});
alert(Auth.getUser(0).name);
// Works 100%
```